# Should [edits] and [editing] be tag synonyms on meta?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, meta, tag-merge

I think the [edits](/questions/tagged/edits) and [editing](/questions/tagged/editing) should be the same (on Meta). I guess there is a small difference (one being the action and one being the edit itself). But the tags are used interchangeably, so I think they should be the same tag. I don't really have a preference as to which one becomes the main tag, but I don't see a great reason to have two separate ones. Thoughts?

Comment: uses stats: edits 13, editing 208 currently. It seems wise to leave `editing` and put `edits` and `edit` as synonyms.